# Deleting edges within a face

Tags: edges

How do I delete the four diagonal edges (the 1414mm ones) so I can have one continuous face rather than four?

I pressed <kbd>X</kbd>  and tried *Dissolve Edge* and *Edge Collapse* but none works without messing up the model.

I tried *Limited Dissolve* but it only allows me to delete up to two edges not all four.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't. A single face can't have a hole, in Blender. It must be bounded by a single loop of edges, and when traced round, each edge must have only one direction (which is why you can't leave only one edge, either).  Can we ask why you want the edges removed, to suggest alternatives?

Comment: Posted new image to clarify. So it's not possible to delete the remaining 2 diagonal edges to form a single surface for the bottom platform? Thought it might be easier to work with later on (click one surface rather than two).

Comment: Don't know whether you'll get this comment .For good reasons, Blender, and most fully-featured polygonal modelers, are geared to quad loops. In face mode, Alt-clicking on one of the diagonals will select all the faces in the border loop.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that useful tip. I'm new to Blender, still trying to understand how it works.

Comment: Just read another post linked by Duarte. Basically the answer is no and there is no need.